# AxVLCPlugin2 always show toolbar VB.net

Tags: vb.net, vlc, libvlc

Im using AxVLCPlugin2. By default the toolbar auto hides. I would like for it to stay put. Cant find the right command if there is one. Im using VB.net Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You notice how the toolbar stays on when you wave the mouse over the control? You can simulate that. Drop a timer onto your form, set it to, let's say default 100ms interval and enable it. Then put following code into Timer_Tick event handler:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim curPos = Cursor.Position

    Cursor.Hide()
    Cursor.Position = New Point(Me.Left + MyAxVLCPlugin21.Left + 100 * Rnd(1), Me.Top + MyAxVLCPlugin21.Top + 100 * Rnd(1))

    Application.DoEvents()

    Cursor.Position = curPos
    Cursor.Show()

End Sub
```

What this does, every 100ms hides mouse cursor, moves it to a random position over VLC control, then returns back and unhides it. This happens unnoticed by user, but it does the trick - control receives mouse movement and toolbar stays.